# Update in GridView "No value given for one or more parameters"

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, gridview

I have this code (below) and I am getting the following error:

> No value given for one or more parameters

**But when it is run again, values are shown updated for 'RateCenterName', 'QuantityThreshold', 'RateCenterID' but not for 'Province'**

The code:

```
string updateSql = "UPDATE RateCenters SET RateCenterName = ?, Province=?, QuantityThreshold = ?" + " WHERE RateCenterID= ?";     

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{                    
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList2"); // assigning the dropdownlist item to 'ddl'
    TextBox rateCenterName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtRateCenterName"); // assigning textbox input item
    TextBox quantityThreshold = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtQuantityThreshold"); // assigning textbox input item
    Label ratecenterid = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1"); // assigning the label value
    //OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ToString());
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\arjun.giridhar\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BillingApplicationNew\BillingApplicationNew\App_Data\db1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
    OleDbCommand cmd = null;            
    try
    {
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(updateSql, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RateCenterName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = rateCenterName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Province", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuantityThreshold", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToUInt32(quantityThreshold.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RateCenterID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ratecenterid.Text);

        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //GridView1.EditIndex = -1; //refreshing
        //GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what's wrong?

**Moderator edit:**

He solved the problem, but his solution is deep inside one of the comment threads:

> I got it, i removed the Row updating event and just tried it once
>   again without adding that event.

I *think* he means: he took this code out of the RowUpdating event handler and put it elsewhere.

Comment: The at signs are part of the parameter name.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I changed, I am still getting the error

Comment: Please edit your question so we can see the latest version of your code (with each `@` or `?` and the space before `WHERE`).

Comment: @egrunin: I have edited it to the update code!!

Comment: You are **still** omitting the space before `WHERE`.

Comment: @egrunin: oops sorry! Edited now...still same error

Comment: @ArjunBabu - so it work for you...so its time to remove ans...

Comment: @PranayRana: How can I convert ASP.net project file to an .EXE file?  Is it possible for remote user to use the .EXE file?

Comment: @ArjunBabu - not possible to do like that .............

Answer (score 0):

there might be Problem in your code because you are trying to edit access database and you are writing code of sqldatabase....

**You Update Statement code**

```
string updateSql = "UPDATE RateCenters SET RateCenterName =?, Province=? ,
           QuantityThreshold = ? WHERE RateCenterID= ?";
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(scon))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con))
                {

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RateCenterName", str2);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Province", str3);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("QuantityThreshold ", str4);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RateCenterID", str5);


                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Comment: what should i write in the place of str2, str3, str4, str5??

Comment: @ArjunBabu - your texbox and drop down vale what else do you think ? that you did before ...

Comment: @ArjunBabu- are you able to debug the code ........are you getting all values i.e textbox and dropdown data ? if one of them is blank than it might cause issue.............

Comment: I checked it, All the values are read but I hope it is not getting inserted in the parameters

Comment: @ArjunBabu - not recommended but remove the prameter and try to pass the value directly....this might cause sql injection issue but this just for try.............

Comment: Don't forget the @ signs: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RateCenterName", str2);`

Comment: @PranayRana: help me sorting this one out!

Comment: @ArjunBabu - as i told you remove the parameter and pass the data directly something like  string updateSql = "UPDATE RateCenters SET RateCenterName ='"+ str 1+"', Province='"+ str2+"',QuantityThreshold = '"+ str3+"' WHERE RateCenterID= '"+ str4+"'";

Comment: @PranayRana: I got it, i removed the Row updating event and just tried it once again without adding that event. It worked out. Microsoft is great for creating those user controls!

Comment: @egrunin I got it, i removed the Row updating event and just tried it once again without adding that event. It worked out. Microsoft is great for creating those user controls!

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing space before `WHERE` when you are building your SQL.
Line 2 in your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
"WHERE RateCenterID= @RateCenterID"; // this the error. you need to provide space before where
```

you need to add space before Where .

this you should try

```
string updateSql = "UPDATE RateCenters SET RateCenterName = @RateCenterName, Province= 
@Province, QuantityThreshold = @QuantityThreshold" + " WHERE RateCenterID= @RateCenterID";
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is passing a null value to either `RateCenterName` or `Province`.

What happens when you try this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RateCenterName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "rateCenter";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Province", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "ddl";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuantityThreshold", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 0;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RateCenterID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 1;
```